Reversing Newman's representation
In the basic \newman command, the axial substituent points up. Is there a possibility that it points down (in fact, rotate the whole image 180°)?
Because I spent quite a bit of time drawing a cyclohexane molecule and, of course, by bad luck, I drew it in such a way that if I switch to Newman, the front carbon has its axial substituent down!
So, if I want to represent my cyclohexane in Newman, I would like to get this:

whereas currently, I can only do this:

Here my code :
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[all]{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\newman{H,H,,H,,H}\hspace*{-4pt}\newman{H,,H,H,H}

\end{document}

